# working with converted VB to C# code

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatable

I have the following VB code:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = DAL.WMS_Collaboration_Fetch(0).Tables(0)

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    'Bind Dataset to Gridview
    Dim _WMS_CollaborationInfo As New WMS_CollaborationInfo
    With _WMS_CollaborationInfo
        .CollaborationName = dt.Rows(0).Item["CollaborationName").ToString
        .CollaborationID = dt.Rows(0).Item("CollaborationID").ToString
    End With
```

converted it to C# code like this:

```
DataTable dt = DAL.WMS_Collaboration_Fetch(0).Tables(0);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
    //Bind Dataset to Gridview
    WMS_CollaborationInfo _WMS_CollaborationInfo = new WMS_CollaborationInfo();
    {
        _WMS_CollaborationInfo.CollaborationName  = dt.Rows[0].Item["CollaborationName"].ToString;
        _WMS_CollaborationInfo.CollaborationID = dt.Rows[0].Item["CollaborationID"].ToString;
    }
```

I am, however, unable to run the C# code. In VB, the table column, using DataTable, is accessed by just passing in the column name (well, I dont know much about VB) e.g "CollaborationID" in

```
dt.Rows(0).Item("CollaborationID").ToString
```

Please what is the C# equivalent of reading the data  from the table using DataTable? I simply mean how can i re-write my C# code so that it works.

Comment: what? "I am unable to run the C# Code" is too vague. Do you have any exceptions? any compiler error? please be clear

Answer (score 5):

[Indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) in C# use square brackets - `[]`. You also don't need to access `.Item`:

```
_WMS_CollaborationInfo.CollaborationID = 
           dt.Rows[0]["CollaborationID"].ToString();
```

Comment: IIRC, the entire property `Item()` is a VBism for an indexer. So it's likely it's just `Rows[0]["CollaborationID"]`

Comment: For some reason the converters fail to catch this.  Since I use VB.Net I have the opposite issue, going from square brackets to parentheses.

Comment: @millimoose - it is part of the `DataRow` object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.item.aspx

Comment: @Oded The [signature of which](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx#code-snippet-1) is `public Object this[string columnName] { get; set; }`. **All** indexers are documented as a property called `Item`, e.g. [`IList<T>.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewthkb10.aspx) which pretty much everyone always accesses with indexer syntax.

Comment: @Oded In fact poking at LINQPad tells me that all indexers actually seem to compile to a "special" (because it can take arguments) property called (by default) `Item`. You can't even define an indexer and another property called `Item` in the same class.

Comment: @millimoose - Indeed... Some compiler magic goes on. Answer updated.

Comment: For completeness, the name `Item` isn't really magical, you can rename the generated property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02(v=vs.110).aspx#code-snippet-2

Comment: @Oded Ish. For C# it's pretty much a given that many code constructs don't have a straightforward translation into IL (`??`, nullable types), so while it's magic, it's no more magic than should be expected by now :)

Answer (score 5):

In C# there is a distinction between methods and indexers. The first use parenthesis, the second squared braces. This took me a while to grasp while moving from VB where you use parenthesis for both.

Try:

```
dt.Rows[0].Item["CollaborationID"].ToString()
```

**Edit: VB.NET and C# Comparison**

I used to refer to this cheat sheet all the time, check out the Arrays section:
http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

Comment: I had done this at the point of conversion. The question has been updated.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more? what error are you getting? The code above should allow you to read the data from the table.

Comment: I couldn't read the table with the code written like that... But thanks to the link

Comment: What do you mean with you couldn't read it? what's the error?